# SQL Division precision

Tags: sql, sql-server, rounding, division

I have 2 columns which I need to divide sum(cola)/sum(ColB), but I am not getting the desired results since SQL server seems to truncate values after decimal
For eg. I have-

```
select 281370/1035
```

is giving 271 using simple division, whereas actual result of division is `271.8550724637681` and I want to display `271.8`

I tried

```
SELECT cast(round(281370/1035,1) as numeric(36,1))
```

but that results `271.0`

Comment: What types are `colA` and `colB` to start with? Try `SELECT 281370.0/1035.0`. (adding fake decimals often force non-integer computations)

Comment: Well, they're not *fake* decimal places. They really are zeroes.

Comment: both numbers are treated as integers, so it's using integer division. When you used cast, you used it over the result of the integer division. You need to cast either the numerator or denominator first (or you can use `2081370*1.0/1035` which performs an implicit conversion)

Comment: You have to cast before you divide and round if you're going to use that approach. Otherwise the integer rounding (to 0) happens before the cast to decimal.

Comment: Unlike other DBMS, SQL Server uses integer division when both operands are integers, which is something one must be aware of when working with this database system. It's a common source of error in this DBMS and sometimes quite hard to find. Of course one would expect 1 / 2 to result in 0.5, but not so in SQL Server :-(

Comment: @ThorstenKettner if I remember correctly, postgres has the same behavior

Comment: There are other dbms doing integer division as well. Quite handy if you're used to it!

Comment: @Lamak: Ah, I didn't know that. Thanks for poining this out. I like PostgreSQL very much, but things like this can be nasty. It's not good when operands don't behave as a user would expect.

Comment: @jarlh: Yes, but in the very rare cases I want integer division, I'd like to tell the system so. (Rather surprisingly) my favorite is MySQL in this regard: `1 / 2 = 0.5 , 1 DIV 2 = 0`.

Answer (score 5):

In SQL Server, you have to cast the integers to decimal and you could use `Round` to get desired precision.

```
SELECT cast(Round(CAST(281370 AS decimal) / CAST(1035 AS decimal),1,1) as decimal(10,1))
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you given the int number and want a decimal result

try this

```
select convert(decimal(30,10),281370.0/1035.0)
```

or

```
select Round(convert(decimal(30,10),281370.0/1035.0),1,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Stormcloak gives the answer to specifically wanting a single position as a mantissa, however to return an exact answer you could "simply" implicitly change the datatype.

```
select 281370.0/1035
```

Returns:

```
271.855072
```

Comment: Let's be clear: 281370.0/1035 = 271.855072 is not exact by any means. It's certainly closer than 271, but there is plenty of precision lost even when floating point types are used.

Answer (score 0):

In Presto DB:
select (CAST(11 as decimal(8,6))/CAST(7 as decimal(8,6))) as result

result:1.571429

decimal(xp,xs)

- xp--> total number of digits(before decimal point+ after decimal
  point)
- xs--> number of digits after the decimal point

reference: https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/decimal.html